# Multiprocessing Pandas SQL

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, pandasql

I'm getting a table not found error when I utilize multiprocessing on chunked Pandas dataframe in each processor started by the mp library.
I'm using pandasql library for SQL in the following manner:

```
import pandasql import sqldf
pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,4,3,6,1,2], 'b': ['a','a','b','b','c','c','c']})
```

This works for single thread:

```
sorted_df = pysqldf("select * from df order by b, a")
```

It doesn't work when I apply multiprocessing to process each chunk of df in 
parallel:

```
def parallelize_dataframe(df, func):
    unique_bs = df.b.unique().tolist()
    df_split = [df[df.a == l] for l in unique_bs]
    df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, df_split))
    pool = Pool(num_cores)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return df

def sort_chunks(data):
    sorted_data = pysqldf("select * from data order by b, a")
    return sorted_data

sorted_df = parallelize_dataframe(df, sort_chunks)
```

The error I get is the following:

> PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: data
>   [SQL: 'select * from data'] (Background on this error at:
>   http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

I understand what the error is telling me. Basically, the data DF in each processor isn't found in the Database. I'm not sure what would be the workaround for this issue. Any input would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The problem was namespace. Essentially, pysqldf accepts two arguments - query and namespace which is either global or local. If the sqldf function is wrapped inside a function and needs to use a dataframe local to that function, the namespace argument should be locals.

Modifying the sort data function to this below fixed the problem:

```
def sort_chunks(data):
    sorted_data = pysqldf("select * from data order by b, a", locals())
    return sorted_data
```